# Domain mapping with AzureWebAPP and Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, domain-mapping

Is it possible to redirect one domain (MyMenu.com) to two different destinations?

MyMenu.com ---> AzureStorageAccount (StorageAccount URL for static website)

Admin.MyMenu.com ---> AzureWebApp (https://ExampleMenuApp.azurewebsites.net/)

Note: I have a domain from GoDaddy (MyMenu.com). How to make Admin.MyMenu.com ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use rewrite. Code like below in `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(admin.mydevapp.nl)$" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://examplemenuapp.azurewebsites.net/" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

***My domain config on portal.***

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason. In this case URL (https://examplemenuapp.azurewebsites.net/) will be visible to user for storage account which I don't wanna show. Admin user should see only the URL   admin.site.com etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Say you have mymenu.com, which is the root domain, and you have admin.mymenu.com which is a subdomain of mymenu.com. The subdomain is considered as an extension or a child item of the root domain and it can have its own properties, such has pointing to different IPs/websites etc.

Because you're using Azure Storage Account and Azure Web Apps, all you need to do is create two different [CNAMES in Godaddy](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236) that will each point to the different service URL you provided. You also need to verify the domains/subdomains with each individual service before you can assign a domain.

See [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-cname-record) to create a custom domain.